# Error when trying to load data from Unix script

Tags: shell, unix, oracle10g

when i am trying to execute the SQL script from Unix server its showing error but the same SQL i am running from sql navigator its working fine .. kindly help me on it..

```
INSERT INTO t_csocstudent_course_local
(SELECT   tsct.student_id,
          tsct.object_lookup_id,
          tsct.course_id,
          tsct.xcourse_id,
          clt.NAME,
          tsct.course_type,
          FROM   temp_stud_course tsct join course_local clt
   on tsct.COURSE_ID = clt.COURSE_ID

  WHERE   TO_CHAR (sc_timestamp, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') >
              (SELECT   TO_CHAR (MAX (sc_timestamp), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')
                 FROM   t_student_course_local)
          AND tsct.xcourse_id IN
                     ('EX1','EX2'));
```

Error :

```
Error in loading main table
Enter password:
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "WHERE   TO..." - rest of line ignored.
              AND tsct.xcourse_id IN
              *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 1):

I can't remember if the Oracle command line client permits extra whitespace linebreaks.  Remove the extra linebreak before the `WHERE` clause.

#### Update

[From the documentation](http://ss64.com/ora/syntax-sqlplus-set.html), an empty line terminates a SQL statement by default in SQLplus.

```
SQLT[ERMINATOR] {;|c|OFF|ON}| 
   Set the char used to end and execute SQL commands to c. 
   OFF disables the command terminator - use an empty line instead.
   ON resets the terminator to the default semicolon (;).
```

You can change the behavior to use semicolons instead of empty lines:

```
SET SQLTERMINATOR ON
```